# Can we read real time value of parameters passed to callback function using “.apply”?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, jquery-events

In my scenario, I have callback function that accepts some parameters (0 or more). I've declared an object global variable and passing this to my callback function and later in some part of code changing its value, but when I click on `okButton` (mapped to callback function) then function gets called but parameter is coming as undefined. Does anybody have any clue what is wrong in this approach?

**HTML code:**

```
<button id="bindEvents" onclick="BindEvents()">Bind Events</button>
<button id="okButton">Click Me</button>
```

**Some application page:**

```
var tempVariable = {};
function BindEvents() {
    tempVariable.item1 = 100;
    tempVariable.item2 = 200;
    tempVariable.item3 = 300;
    tempVariable.item4 = 400;
    tempVariable.item5 = 500;
}

function callBackFunction(param) {
    var size = Object.keys(param).length;
    if (size > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            alert((i + 1) + ' parameter value: ' + param[i]);
        }
    }
}

testMe({
    okButtonCallback: callBackFunction,
    okButtonCallbackParameters: tempVariable
});
```

**Dynamic.js**

```
var testMe = function (properties) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '#okButton', function () {                properties.okButtonCallback.apply(this, properties.okButtonCallbackParameters); 
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: `apply` takes an *array* of arguments as second parameter, you've passed it an object

Comment: use `.call` or pass in an `array` as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes required to make it working.

**Dynamic.js**
Based on the suggestion from @Bravo and @Robin Zigmond, I've replaced .apply with .call.

```
var testMe = function (properties) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '#okButton', function () {
            properties.okButtonCallback.call(this, properties.okButtonCallbackParameters);
        });
    });
};
```

**Some application page:** Changed the way I was reading parameter

```
function callBackFunction(param) {
    var size = Object.keys(param).length;
    if (size > 0) {
        var valuesArray = Object.values(param)
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            console.log((i + 1) + ' parameter value: ' + valuesArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```